# How to unit test a function inside a Higher Order Function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

How to adapt unit tests for an existing function that needs to be wrapped in a Higher Order Function?

I have two functions. `getServerProps()` fetching data and `isAuthenticated()` checking user authentication. Both in separate modules with their own unit tests.

```
export function isAuthenticated(getServerProps) {
  return async function (param1, param2, param3) {

    const isLoggedIn = await authService()

    if (!isLoggedIn) {
      return { shouldRedirect: true };
    }
    
    const serverProps = await getServerProps(param1, param2, param3);
    return { shouldRedirect: false, ...serverProps };
  };
}
```

.

```
export async function getServerProps(param1, param2, param3) {
  const data = new DataService(param1, param2, param3);
  return { ...data };
}
```

Changing the export of the second function to `isAuthenticated(getServerProps)` mixes two functions in one unit. How to isolate the initial `getServerProps()` for the purpose of unit testing?

What's the best way to write tests in such a situation?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question...

Comment: Have you tried mocking the function you don't want to test?